# Base64 decode crash android

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, decode

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64`

```
val base64 = Base64.decode(string3, Base64.URL_SAFE)
val str = String(base64, charset("UTF-8"))
```

`string3 = "eyJzdWNjZXNzIjp0cnVlLCJyZWFzb25zIjp7IjUiOiJMYXRlIGFycml2YWwgYXQgU2Nob29sIiwiNiI6IkVhcmx5IGRlcGFydHVyZSIsIjkiOiJMYXRlIGFycml2YWwgdG8gQ2xhc3MiLCI4MSI6IkNPVklELTE5IE9uLVByZW1pc2UifSwicmFuZCI6MTg3OTM0NDIxOSwidGltZSI6MTU5MDAzMzM5OH0%3D"`

It only happens sometimes.

Most of the time it works.

`string3` can successfully decoded by the online decode tool.

I try following fixes

Use -> 
`Base64.URL_SAFE`
`Base64.DEFAULT`
`Base64.NO_PADDING`
`Base64.NO_WRAP`

```
val remainder = string3.length % 4
   if (remainder > 0) {
     val pad = "=";
     val char = pad.single()
     string3.padStart(string3.length + 4 - remainder, char)
   }
```

Sometimes it crash.. sometimes it working peacefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64` your string is not a proper encoded string , You can check here

- [Base64 Decoder](https://base64.guru/tools/validator)
- [Base64 Validator](https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder)

It clearly show the error(marked in red), remove those characters and you can verify and check again.

- [Repair Base64](https://base64.guru/tools/repair)

Comment: There is an invalid character on my string3. "%" invalid character that's why it crashes.